# How do i make the texture transparent?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the method which increase transparent texture, alpha = 0.3f.

```
 public void setUpTransparent(float alpha){
        up += 1;
        rgbBatch = batch.getColor();
        if (up > 100){
            batch.setColor(rgbBatch.r, rgbBatch.g, rgbBatch.b, alpha);
            batch.draw(textureIcon, rectangleIcon.x, rectangleIcon.y);
        }
    }
```

I need do dicrease transparent for texture. How do this ?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. The above should work if you've set up your batch with the right blend mode and enabled blending on the batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setUpTransparent(float alpha){
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    batch.begin();

    up++;
    rgbBatch = batch.getColor();
    if (up > 100){
        batch.setColor(rgbBatch.r, rgbBatch.g, rgbBatch.b, alpha);
        batch.draw(textureIcon, rectangleIcon.x, rectangleIcon.y);
    }
    batch.end();
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. SprtieBatch manages GL state on its own, and if you modify it between `batch.begin()`/`end()`, it will have unexpected results.